# How to set the layout margins of edit text boxes?

Tags: java, android, ellipse

In the table layout i have a tablerow and in that tablerow i have 6 edit text boxes and i want to set the layout margins for that 6 edit text boxes

```
TableLayout t1=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_layout01);

  TableRow tr1=new TableRow(inventory.this);
  tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


  tr1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
  EditText ed6=new EditText(inventory.this);
  //ed6.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  /*ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams editmargin=new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  editmargin.setMargins(leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin);*/


  ed6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  ed6.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


  ed6.setText("1");
        tr1.addView(ed6);



  EditText ed7=new EditText(inventory.this);
  //ed7.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  ed7.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  ed7.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  ed7.setText("2");

  tr1.addView(ed7);

  EditText ed8=new EditText(inventory.this);
  //ed8.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  ed8.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  ed8.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  ed8.setText("3");

  tr1.addView(ed8);

  EditText ed9=new EditText(inventory.this);
  //ed9.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  ed9.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  ed9.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  ed9.setText("4");

  tr1.addView(ed9);

  EditText ed10=new EditText(inventory.this);
  //ed10.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  ed10.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  ed10.setText("5");
  ed10.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

  tr1.addView(ed10);

  EditText ed11=new EditText(inventory.this);
  //ed11.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  ed11.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  ed11.setText("6");
  ed11.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

  tr1.addView(ed11);

  t1.addView(tr1);
```

Answer (score 10):

first of all something you should know: According to the [Official Android Dev Pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), Views (and a TextView derives from View) do not support the setting of Margin, but ViewGroups (such as `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc...) do.

So what you could do is the following:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
TextView view = new TextView(this);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This would set the margin for all children to 5 pixels - I tried it and it worked for me (albeit with a `LinearLayout` with vertical alignment). Give it a shot and let me know if I can help further :) .

Cheers,

Ready4Fajir

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**
I would try with the XML below (you'd, of course, update the id's etc.). The "magic" in the xml is that it distributes all available width evenly among the `TextView`'s (and the `EditText`'s on the second row).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The first "row" -->    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView 01"
            android:id="@+id/textView01" />

        <!-- Here you'd add your other five TextView's accordingly -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The second "row" -->    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView 01"
            android:id="@+id/editText01" />

        <!-- Here you'd add your other five EditText's accordingly -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Java code you could then access your EditText views like:

```
EditText editText01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText01);
editText01.setText("1");
```

I have now ignored the fact that you need to create your EditText's programatically. Do you *really*, ***really*** need to create them in Java? (Why?)

**OLD ANSWER:**
If you just want to set the layout margins to your EditText view i quess you could use the `setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)` function call on the `LayoutParams` variable.

```
int left = 6;
int top = 12;
int right = 6;
int bottom = 6;

TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

EditText edXY = new EditText(inventory.this);
edXY.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you ultimately wish to distribute all available space evenly among the six EditText views in a table row I would suggest you have a look at the following post: [2-column TableLayout with 50% exactly for each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725024/2-column-tablelayout-with-50-exactly-for-each-column)

Comment: OK. What are the symptoms? What is the expected- and the actual behaviour?

Comment: actually i have a table layout.in that i have two table rows. in first tablerow i have six columns and each column have each textview. in second row i have six cedittext boxes and i want that second row to be like the first row means same marginal layout.i created the first row in xml.but can't create the second row in xml bcoz i have to do that programmatically...

Comment: I have now modified my answer according to the **EDIT:** section

Comment: but i have to creat in java it's the need of project

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow oderwise i can show you the screenshot of what i want