# dynamic margin inside edittext

Tags: android

First, let me say, new to java, new to android. I'm attacking this head- with an ambitious first real project, a special kind of text editor. 
I have figured out styling using spannables, but thats not particularly important.
I need a dynamic margin inside edittext. when I click the button, I want it to indent all of the text after that, on both left and right, until there is a carriage return, then it should drop back to no indent on a new line.

Think dialog in a play for an example of the output.

Thanks in advance for any information you might lend.

Comment: Yeah, you're looking for a hanging indent. Would be nice, but really, I don't think there's any easy way to do it in Android without writing a very complex custom TextView class (and personally, I wouldn't really know where to start).

Answer (score 0):

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814788/how-to-set-the-layout-margins-of-edit-text-boxes) (look at the OLD ANSWER part) should help you solve the margin problem, but you can't have two different margins in one edit text. Consider creating a new edit text when a user presses carriage return or something of the sort.

Hope it helps.