# TableLayout (TableRow?) not sizing child Views as expected when adding them dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

**Context:** I have a TableLayout (created using XML), which has one TableRow, which has one TextView. The code:

```
 <ScrollView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
  <TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/mytable"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:stretchColumns="1"
     >
    <TableRow>
      <TextView
     android:id="@+id/add_alarm"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="New\nItem"
     android:textSize="30sp"
     />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In my Activity's onCreate() method, I am trying to add another View to the TableRow dynamically. Here is the code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.mytable);

        TableRow tr = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(0);
        Log.d(TAG, "tr class = " + tr.getClass().getName() + " | width = " + tr.getWidth() + "\n");
        final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_widget, null);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        tr.addView(rl, lp); 
        tl.invalidate();
        setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

**Question:** This code is not having the intended effect of displaying both the Views (the one in the XML layout already & the other added dynamically) in a columns of equal width.

1. With the code given above, the dynamically added View has a width of '0' and is therefore invisible.
2. If I change the code to `tr.addView(rl)` (i.e. without reference to LayoutParams), the dynamically added view is visible, but the columns are not equal in width.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:** I changed the code based on the comments to the following. It still doesn't work as expected:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                               TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
tr.addView(rl, lp);
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725024/2-column-tablelayout-with-50-exactly-for-each-column/4725128#4725128) is similar to yours (the accepted answer would be the one I recommend - note the comments as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this behavior defined for [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html):

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

Rather than add your text views directly to the TableRow, have the TableRow hold a horizontal LinearLayout and add the second view to that holder.

(Also, using LinearLayout.LayoutParams for something that's going into a TableRow is wrong. You should have been using [TableRow.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html). But that wouldn't be the way to get equal-width TextViews. Use a LinearLayout holder.)

Comment: Thanks for the TableRow.LayoutParams tip. Fixed it (check edit to question). However, I'm not sure how using a LinearLayout is going to help. Isn't a TableRow basically a 'thin' extension of a horizontal LinearLayout in the first place? Also, how would one achieve equal-width child Views within a LinearLayout?

Comment: for a linear layout, equal-width child views can easily be achieved by setting layout_width=0dip and layout_weight=1.

Comment: Which is the same as how it is achieved with a TableLayout. And doing to programmatically is not working with TableLayout -- it may not work with a LinearLayout as well (unless there's a bug in the former)

Comment: Just read the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725024/2-column-tablelayout-with-50-exactly-for-each-column/4725128#4725128 -- let me try it out and get back to you.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda - The reason that Josephus's technique will work for a linear layout but not for a TableRow is that a TableRow (as the docs say) specifically ignores the layout_width and layout_weight parameters. You can just put in a LinearLayout in place of the TableRow and it should lay out at the full table width and divide its children equally.

Comment: So, the LinearLayout trick seems to be working. I still don't understand why the width=0/weight=1 trick works with TableLayout in XML, but doesn't work through Java code.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda - It should work from code as well. Are you sure you're adding the new view to the LinearLayout and not to the TableRow?

Comment: @TedHopp, the width=0/weight=1 trick works for LinearLayout, both, from code & XML. However, it seems to work for TableLayout only from XML, not from code.

Comment: actually all of that helped me.
but im still asking me - like saurabh - why it is working without linearlayout as a child of the tablerow when using xml.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to dynamically add an item to a TableRow - it defeats the purpose of using a table. Imagine if you add an item to the first row of the table, but not on the second, meaning the first row has more elements. It wouldn't look much like a table.

But if you insist,

From developer guide:

```
The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.
```

You may need to start looking on the layout_weight of each element. Try adding `layout_weight=1` on the row's static elements, and then setting your dynamic RelativeLayout's weight to 1 before adding it to the row.

```
rl.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

The last parameter is weight.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have different number of items in each row through XML as well?

Comment: sure you can. i'm just against that design :) have you tried if it works using the weight?

Comment: I tried with width=FILL_PARENT & weight=1, but it didn't work. (I've edited the question to reflect this).

Comment: will try to do the code in ide later. right now i'm downloading android sdk.

Comment: have you tried layout_width=0dip? check out this link http://androidadvice.blogspot.com/2010/10/tablelayout-columns-equal-width.html

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. (check code snippet in question). Is there a different way to define layout_width=0dp programmatically?

Comment: I mean use 0dp also with the static elements. Using 0dp on one element while fill_parent on the others will really hide your dynamic layout.

Answer (score 0):

Set height like this to the layout containing the ScrollView.
It solved my own problem where tablelayout does not show last lines.

android:layout_height="0dp"