# Android Develop: Table Layout does not show all my Table Rows in the Same Size

Tags: android, layout, row, tablelayout

i've a Table Layout...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">



        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg01"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg02"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg03"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg04"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg05"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg06"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg07"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg08"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg09"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg10"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg11"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg12"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg13"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg14"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg15"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg16"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg17"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg18"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg19"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg20"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg21"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg22"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg23"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg24"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg25"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg26"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg27"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg28"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg29"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg30"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg31"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg32"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg33"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg34"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg35"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg36"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg37"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg38"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg39"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>   
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg40"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg41"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/botImg42"
                android:clickable="true"  
                android:onClick="imageClick"/>  
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
```

But I can't see the last TableRow's Images!

In all 6 rows should appear those Image Views. They may be scaled if they wouldn't suit to the screen. But they don't!

What's the Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.
Rather than add your text views directly to the TableRow, have the TableRow hold a horizontal LinearLayout and add the second view to that holder.
Source: [TableLayout (TableRow?) not sizing child Views as expected when adding them dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538113/tablelayout-tablerow-not-sizing-child-views-as-expected-when-adding-them-dyna)