# TextView not matching parent width

Tags: java, android

My TextView can't get parent WIDTH using...

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

And

```
textview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

It only takes the width of text.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

EDIT: Okay after a big search I found the solution of my problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538241/2535288

Comment: Did you try `LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`?

Comment: @neo108 "FILL_PARENT - The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent."

Comment: Thanks @Marek. Somehow missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This should be working fine. To see that it is, try setting the TextView's background color:

```
textview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorChosen);
```

If you want the text to center itself inside the TextView:

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: The 'TextView' disappeared after setting the Layout Parameters?